# C# MVC Loop through list and update each record efficiently

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, loops

I have a list of 'Sites' that are stored in my database. The list is VERY big and contains around 50,000+ records.

I am trying to loop through each record and update it. This takes ages, is there a better more efficient way of doing this?

```
  using (IRISInSiteLiveEntities DB = new IRISInSiteLiveEntities())
        {
            var allsites = DB.Sites.ToList();

                foreach( var sitedata in allsites)
                {


                            var siterecord = DB.Sites.Find(sitedata.Id);

                            siterecord.CabinOOB = "Test";
                            siterecord.TowerOOB = "Test";
                            siterecord.ManagedOOB = "Test";
                            siterecord.IssueDescription = "Test";
                            siterecord.TargetResolutionDate = "Test";

                            DB.Entry(siterecord).State = EntityState.Modified;

                }

            DB.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I have cut the stuff out of the code to get to the point. The proper function code I am using basically pulls a list out from Excel, then matches the records in the sites list and updates each record that matches accordingly. The DB.Find is slowing the loop down dramatically.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadUpdateOOBList()
    {
        CheckPermissions("UpdateOOBList");

        string[] typesallowed = new string[] { ".xls", ".xlsx" };

        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
        var fname = file.FileName;

        if (!typesallowed.Any(fname.Contains))
        {
            return Json("NotAllowed");
        }

        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/OOB List/") + fname);

        //Create empty OOB data list
        List<OOBList.OOBDetails> oob_data = new List<OOBList.OOBDetails>();

        //Using ClosedXML rather than Interop Excel....
        //Interop Excel: 30 seconds for 750 rows
        //ClosedXML: 3 seconds for 750 rows
        string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/OOB List/") + fname;
        using (var excelWorkbook = new XLWorkbook(fileName))
        {
            var nonEmptyDataRows = excelWorkbook.Worksheet(2).RowsUsed();

            foreach (var dataRow in nonEmptyDataRows)
            {
                //for row number check
                if (dataRow.RowNumber() >= 4 )
                {

                    string siteno = dataRow.Cell(1).GetValue<string>();
                    string sitename = dataRow.Cell(2).GetValue<string>();
                    string description = dataRow.Cell(4).GetValue<string>();
                    string cabinoob = dataRow.Cell(5).GetValue<string>();
                    string toweroob = dataRow.Cell(6).GetValue<string>();
                    string manageoob = dataRow.Cell(7).GetValue<string>();
                    string resolutiondate = dataRow.Cell(8).GetValue<string>();
                    string resolutiondate_converted = resolutiondate.Substring(resolutiondate.Length - 9);

                    oob_data.Add(new OOBList.OOBDetails
                    {
                        SiteNo = siteno,
                        SiteName = sitename,
                        Description = description,
                        CabinOOB = cabinoob,
                        TowerOOB = toweroob,
                        ManageOOB = manageoob,
                        TargetResolutionDate = resolutiondate_converted
                    });

                }
            }
        }

        //Now delete file.
        System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/OOB List/") + fname);

        Debug.Write("DOWNLOADING LIST ETC....\n");

        using (IRISInSiteLiveEntities DB = new IRISInSiteLiveEntities())
        {
            var allsites = DB.Sites.ToList();

            //Loop through sites and the OOB list and if they match then tell us
            foreach( var oobdata in oob_data)
            {
                foreach( var sitedata in allsites)
                {

                    var indexof = sitedata.SiteName.IndexOf(' ');

                    if( indexof > 0 )
                    {
                        var OOBNo = oobdata.SiteNo;
                        var OOBName = oobdata.SiteName;
                        var SiteNo = sitedata.SiteName;
                        var split = SiteNo.Substring(0, indexof);

                        if (OOBNo == split && SiteNo.Contains(OOBName) )
                        {
                            var siterecord = DB.Sites.Find(sitedata.Id);

                            siterecord.CabinOOB = oobdata.CabinOOB;
                            siterecord.TowerOOB = oobdata.TowerOOB;
                            siterecord.ManagedOOB = oobdata.ManageOOB;
                            siterecord.IssueDescription = oobdata.Description;
                            siterecord.TargetResolutionDate = oobdata.TargetResolutionDate;

                            DB.Entry(siterecord).State = EntityState.Modified;

                            Debug.Write("Updated Site ID/Name Record: " + sitedata.Id + "/" + sitedata.SiteName);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            DB.SaveChanges();
        }

        var nowdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/OOB List/lastupdated.txt"),nowdate);

        return Json("Success");

    }
```

Comment: I can't speak for excel specifically but rather than using Find and passing an ID to retrieve a single record, you should consider retrieving the first 5000 records, updating them, then the next 5000 etc. it would at least make the read part much faster, although writing them individually would still be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using Entity Framework (6 or Core). In either case both

```
var siterecord = DB.Sites.Find(sitedata.Id);
```

and

```
DB.Entry(siterecord).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

are redundant, because the `siteData` variable is coming from

```
var allsites = DB.Sites.ToList();
```

This not only loads the whole `Site` table in memory, but also EF change tracker keeps reference to every object from that list. You can easily verify that with

```
var siterecord = DB.Sites.Find(sitedata.Id);
Debug.Assert(siterecord == sitedata);
```

The `Find` (when the data is already in memory) and `Entry` methods themselves are fast. But the problem is that they by default trigger automatic `DetectChanges`, which leads to quadratic time complexity - in simple words, very slow.

With that being said, simply remove them:

```
if (OOBNo == split && SiteNo.Contains(OOBName))
{
    sitedata.CabinOOB = oobdata.CabinOOB;
    sitedata.TowerOOB = oobdata.TowerOOB;
    sitedata.ManagedOOB = oobdata.ManageOOB;
    sitedata.IssueDescription = oobdata.Description;
    sitedata.TargetResolutionDate = oobdata.TargetResolutionDate;

    Debug.Write("Updated Site ID/Name Record: " + sitedata.Id + "/" + sitedata.SiteName);    
}
```

This way EF will detect changes just once (before `SaveChanges`) and also will update only the modified record fields.

Comment: Thank. I did not know this at all. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you should turn your HTTPPost in an async function 
more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

What you then should do is create the tasks and add them to a list. Then wait for them to complete (if you want/need to) by calling Task.WaitAll()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.7.2

This will allow your code to run in parallel on multiple threads optimizing performance quite a bit already.

You can also use linq to for example reduce the size of allsites beforehand by doing something that will roughly look like this

var sitedataWithCorrectNames = allsites.Where(x => x //evaluate your condition here)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities

and then start you foreach (var oobdata) with the now foreach(sitedate in sitedataWithCorrectNames)

Same goes for SiteNo.Contains(OOBName)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq

P.S. Most db sdk's also provide asynchornous functions so use those aswell. 
P.P.S. I didn't have an IDE so I eyeballed the code but the links should provide you with plenty of samples. Reply if you need more help.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion: var allsites = DB.Sites.Where(x => x.SiteName.IndexOf(' ') > 0).ToList();

But what would i do in regrading optimisating this part: 

 var indexof = sitedata.SiteName.IndexOf(' ');
                        var split = SiteNo.Substring(0, indexof);

                        if (OOBSiteNo == split && SiteNo.Contains(OOBSiteName))
                        {

Comment: I get the following error after trying your suggestion: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: My bad, turns out IndexOf is not support. What are you trying to check with it btw? Maybe you can use Contains for instance or another method. There are plenty of methods  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities

Comment: I would recommend you start with the async stuff though. That should really boost performance.

Comment: Can you use async stuff with from a AJAX call? The function is from a AJAX call.

Comment: Ofcourse, the client application doesn't care as long as you implement it properly

Answer (score 0):

I have followed Ivan Stoev's suggestion and have changed the code by removing the DB.Find and the EntitySate Modified - It now takes about a minute and a half compared to 15 minutes beforehand. Very suprising as I didn't know that you dont actually require that to update the records. Clever. The code is now:

```
using (IRISInSiteLiveEntities DB = new IRISInSiteLiveEntities())
        {
            var allsites = DB.Sites.ToList();

            Debug.Write("Starting Site Update loop...");

            //Loop through sites and the OOB list and if they match then tell us
            //750 records takes around 15-20 minutes.

            foreach( var oobdata in oob_data)
            {
                foreach( var sitedata in allsites)
                {

                    var indexof = sitedata.SiteName.IndexOf(' ');

                    if( indexof > 0 )
                    {
                        var OOBNo = oobdata.SiteNo;
                        var OOBName = oobdata.SiteName;
                        var SiteNo = sitedata.SiteName;
                        var split = SiteNo.Substring(0, indexof);

                        if (OOBNo == split && SiteNo.Contains(OOBName) )
                        {
                            sitedata.CabinOOB = oobdata.CabinOOB;
                            sitedata.TowerOOB = oobdata.TowerOOB;
                            sitedata.ManagedOOB = oobdata.ManageOOB;
                            sitedata.IssueDescription = oobdata.Description;
                            sitedata.TargetResolutionDate = oobdata.TargetResolutionDate;

                            Debug.Write("Thank you, next: " + sitedata.Id + "\n");
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            DB.SaveChanges();
        }
```